# Can't see a JSON field in GET response (mongoose)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, mongodb, mongoose

I have this JSON document (as seen in [mongolab](http://mongolab.com)):

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "566e8673eb862d165fef7171"
    },
    "street": "Dizingof",
    "buildingNumber": 33,
    "apartmentNumber": 63,
    "beds": 3,
    "owner": {
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "564374944cb813541afc193a"
        },
        "local": {
            "password": "$2a$08$PtZrvLY7MWSi44gMDSjLJ.u4x.IOXIkRFZYfQhAwt.5vSIXpCYjX6",
            "email": "someemail@gmail.com"
        },
        "__v": 0
    }
}
```

Which the `owner` field in its schema is defined as:

```
owner           :  {
                type: Schema.ObjectId,
                ref: 'User'
        }
```

And when I perform `http.get` to get the listing I receive back:

```
{
  "_id": "566e8673eb862d165fef7171",
  "street": "Dizingof",
  "buildingNumber": 33,
  "apartmentNumber": 63,
  "beds": 3,
  "imagesAndCount": [],
  "UsersAndQuestions": []
}
```

Why can't I see/use the `owner` field? I need it for manipulations of my HTML document.

Edit: this is the relevant GET in `routes.js`:

```
app.get('/api/listing/:street/:buildingNumber/:apartmentNumber', function (req, res) {
        Listing.findOne(
            {
                "street": req.params.street,
                "buildingNumber": req.params.buildingNumber,
                "apartmentNumber": req.params.apartmentNumber
            }
            , function (err, listing) {
                if (err) { return next(err); }
                res.json(listing);
            });
    });
```

Also, I populated the `owner` field by doing this:

```
var myUser = db.users.findOne()
db.listings.insert({"street" : "Dizingof", "buildingNumber" : 33, "apartmentNumber" : 63, "beds": 3, "owner": myUser})
```

Comment: could you show the query you're doing?

Comment: @Alex i'm using POSTMAN for the query: http://localhost:3000/api/listing/Dizingof/33/63

Comment: no, i mean your query to mongodb. you've tagged mongoose, so you must be querying mongodb with that somewhere

Comment: thanks - how do you populate this data? You've set the type of `owner` to `ref` in your schema, but this looks like you've pumped other data into that field?

Comment: @Alex edited my post again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is this

```
owner :{
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
}
```

Mongoose is expecting a reference to a document, to then hydrate using `populate` (which only works in arrays of types by the way) so is not returning it as part of your query.

Assuming you're using 4.2 of mongoose, you can do something like:

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html#altsyntax

```
var ownerSchema= new Schema({ name: 'string', otherProperty: 'string' });

var parentSchema = new Schema({
  owner: ownerSchema
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried defining    "  owner           : [User]   "  But I still just get an empty array in my GET resonse JSON... How could I actually get a User object?

Comment: You're now specifying an array, but storing a single object... it needs to be one or the other.

Comment: also, are you wanting to store the User object as an embedded document, or in its own collection?

Comment: When I tried to : owner           : User    it gave me an error: TypeError: Undefined type at `owner`

Comment: I just want to have it as "hard-coded" object that doesn't need to be changed later even if that specific User was updated

Comment: embedded document then. What version of mongoose are you using?

Comment: Looks like ~3.8.1 in the package.json

Comment: you need to use 4.2 to use schema defined single embedded documents vs array of embedded docs

Comment: Just upgraded to 4.2 , doesn't seem to make a difference... What piece of code should work here?

Comment: read "Single Embedded Subdocs" here - http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html#altsyntax

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97834/discussion-between-idos-and-alex).